# How can I start mysql by command service mysql start

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I can start mysql by following command

```
/etc/init.d/mysql.server start
```

But I want to start it by command "service mysql start"

Server is debian 10.

Mariadb, which was originally installed, was uninstalled and mysql 5.5 was reinstalled.

Comment: you can also do ' sudo mysql ' , it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way for debian10 is now:

```
systemctl start mysql.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sysvinit, the service name should be the name of the file inside /etc/init.d. In your case, the file name is mysql.server, so "sudo service mysql.server start{stop, status, restart}" should be the command used. If it isn't referenced anywhere else, you could even rename the file from "mysql.server" to "mysql" and just run "sudo service mysql start".